# Is it possible for linear homogeneous differential equation to have solutions $x$and $sin(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to make a linear homogeneous second order differential equation whose general solution is:

$f(x) = c_1 x + c_2 \sin(x)$

Comment: Have you tried computing $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and playing with that?

Comment: What about the coefficients of the linear DE, are they to be constants?

Comment: Note that $x$ and $\sin x$ both have initial conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$ at $x = 0$: so any such equation would have to be singular at $x = 0$.  (For example, in Rene Schipperus's solution, $1 - x \cot x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, so $y'' - \frac{x}{1 - x \cot x} y' + \frac{1}{1 - x \cot x} y = 0$ has the required singularity at $x = 0$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(1-x\cot x)y^{\prime\prime}-xy^{\prime}+y=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed, thanks to Rene Schippernus, that the question asks for second order.  So I guess I goofed and read too fast . . . Nevertheless, for the sake of general knowledge, here is a *constant coefficient* solution of order $4$:

With

$f(x) = c_1x + c_2 \sin x, \tag 1$

we have

$f'(x) = c_1 + c_2 \cos x, \tag 2$

$f''(x) = -c_2 \sin x, \tag 3$

so that

$f'' + f = c_1 x; \tag 4$

then

$(f'' + f)' = c_1, \tag 5$

and

$(f'' + f)'' = 0; \tag 6$

also,

$(f'' + f)'' = f^{(4)} + f^{(2)} = \dfrac{d^4f}{dx^4} + \dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}, \tag 7$

so

$\dfrac{d^4f}{dx^4} + \dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2} = f^{(4)} + f^{(2)} = 0 \tag 8$

is such an equation.  Note that (8) is both linear and homogeneous; if there is a simpler (e.g. lower order) solution, I don't know of it.

Comment: That equation has order four and thus must have four independent solutions. So the given form is not the general solution.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus:  yes, I just noticed that.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry to be annoying.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus:  not annoying at all.  Thanks again for pointing out my error.  Now at least I look *slightly* less foolish! ;)